# Variable Is Accessed Within Inner Class Needs to be Declared Final with MediaPlayer In a OnTouchListener

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I am making an app where a sound (e.g. music) plays only when a button is pressed. I have it so android studio wont' give me any problems except this:  I get an error at the places where I put mp.start; and mp.stop; (mp is my mediaplayer) and, even if I don't put that code in the app unextendedly stops when I press the button. here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        Button ImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mp.start;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mp.stop;
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make mp as final  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

Comment: why comment and copy what you've just read in another answer?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is explained in the title - simply make the variable you are using `final`. The following change:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

You are calling the mp variable from a different *scope*.

You can [read about variable scope here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) - the code inside your onTouchListener is not run at the same time as the code inside onCreate. So marking mp final tells the onTouchListener "it's safe to keep a reference to this object, it can't be changed anymore so it will still be the correct object when you run in the future"

Answer (score -1):

Try this code .
Make mp as final.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

Or make mp as member variable of class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                MediaPlayer mp;

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
                Button ImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                ImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                mp.start;
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                mp.stop;
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```